# How do I read the ASP.Net bitness of an existing application pool in an Installshield Custom Action?

Tags: vbscript, installshield, custom-action

In our Installation, I run a custom action to set the bitness to match the target machine's IIS configuration.

```
if SYSINFO.bIsWow64 <> 0 then ' and  NOT Installed - not working
    Session.Property("ASPBITNESS") = "x64"  
    Session.Property("ALLOWTHIRTYTWOBIT") = "false"
    ' Session.Property("OLDBITNESS") = "x64" How do I read this value?
end if
```

The problem now is for upgrades, I would like to check if that Application pool already exists and skip the Custom Action. The problem is the Not Installed condition isn't working so I would like to read the property from the vbscript CA.

Has anyone got any experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why would an installer need to know the bitness of an application pool?  Just set it to what you want or better create your own new app pool with it set to what you want.    Why do you need a custom action for this?  InstallShield has native IIS support where you just author this into the tables and let IS handle the  rest.

Comment: It's my application pool from the previous version. We had problems when the bitness of the installing version didn't match that of the target system's IIS. I've now written some script to change it to match at the start, but that breaks upgrades to systems that were already installed mismatched. So I was trying to only run my script above on fresh installs

Comment: Have you tried creating two app pools with different bitness and then associate them to two different components?  You can then put mutually exclusive conditions on the components so that one or the other gets installed.  Tied to an AppSearch to set the property to control which one gets installed.  The point is, you should be able to do all of this without writing any script / custom actions.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Create two app pools with opposite bitness and then associate them to two different components. Place mutually exclusive conditions on the components so that one or the other gets installed. Tied to an AppSearch to set the property to control which one gets installed. The point is, you should be able to do all of this without writing any script / custom actions.